# Where is document.documentElement used?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have been learning javascript for a while. Recently I got to know about document.documentElement. It simply refers to the html root tag in the browser / html documents.

Are there any other uses of this.

Could some please share the real world uses of document.documentElement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is far too broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly My question is simple and direct. What is broad here?

Comment: You're asking for generic usage examples. There is no one answer to this question.

Comment: document.documentElement - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.documentElement

Comment: @JamesDonnelly My concern is with the practical / real world uses. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a shortcut property that refers to the document's root Element node; in HTML this would be the html element.

This property is readonly.

There is no other use of this ;)

[DOC HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/document.documentElement)

Answer (score 0):

It's just a privilege to get the root element of the document. This property is read only.
 You can find more about it on mozilla documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.documentElement

Answer (score 0):

Rajesh,

1. Document Object Model (DOM) Tree Hierarchy Viewing - In Google Chrome, 'right click' on a webpage, and select "Inspect Element", then select the tab 'Console'. In the console type 'document.documentElement;' to view the DOM of that webpage (same as is shown in the 'Element' tab. If you type 'console.log($('html').parentNode);' in 'Console' it will return the document containing the html file (i.e. #document)
2. DOM Viewing (Partial) - In the 'Console' tab mentioned above, type 'document.documentElement.childNodes;' to only view the child nodes. 'document.body.innerHTML' returns the body.
3. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) - If you install jQuery, you can view the DOM by just typing '$('html')' in the 'Console' mentioned above. If jQuery is running, 'true' will be returned when you type '$ === jQuery' in the 'Console'.